# How to implement LRU algorithm?

Tags: caching, lru

I'm writing a program that simulates LRU caching, the program function should look to the cache to see whether the new input is inside it, if its already there just increment the number of hits and the frequency of the index that contains the element, if the input is not in the cache and the cache still have empty space, just push the input into the cache. if the cache has no space and the input is not inside it, get the index with the least frequency and push the input inside it, then reset the frequency of the index to 0. However I didn't get the expected result. After some analysis, I figured that I didn't handle the case of two indexes with the same minimum frequency. I have no idea how to handle that, do you?

Comment: visit here [http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lru-cache-implementation/](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lru-cache-implementation/)

Comment: One approach is to pick one of the two (or more) entries with the minimum frequency at random.